# JDBC Select from Select ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, select, jdbc

this is my tables:

```
table Paciente
+------------------------------------+
|   Nome   |   RG   |   ID_Paciente  |
+------------------------------------+
|  Lucas   |  10101 |        1       |
+------------------------------------+

table Telefone
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  DDD   |   Telefone   |   ID_Paciente  |   ID_Telefone  |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|   41   |   123456789  |        1       |       1        |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to print DDD and Telefone from the table Telefone.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
String sql = "select ID_Paciente from Paciente where Nome = '"+nome+"'";
PreparedStatement st = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();

sql = "select DDD from Telefone where ID_Paciente = '"+res.getString(1)+"'";
st = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);

res = st.executeQuery();

while(res.next())
{   
      System.out.println("  DDD: "+res.getString(1));
}
```

But, it's not working

some help?

Comment: put res.next() before 2nd sql statement

Comment: Define "it's not working". What happens? The exception you get contains a meaningful message, intended to be read. Also, re-read the tutorial about ptepared statements, because you missed the whole point, which is to be able to bind parameters safely, without using String concatenation.

Comment: why don't you join the queries instead of firing two different select statements?

Comment: I'm quite worried, if paciente means what I think it does and this isn't a homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can answer your question, I don't think it is a good approach to fire two select statements separately. You can combine the statements and fire one query :

```
"select DDD from Telefone where ID_Paciente in (select ID_Paciente from Paciente where Nome = '"+nome+"')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join instead of 2 execute queries

```
SELECT Telefone.DDD, Telefone.Telefone, 
FROM Telefone
INNER JOIN Paciente
ON Telefone.ID_Paciente=Paciente.ID_Paciente;


String sql = "SELECT Telefone.DDD, Telefone.Telefone, 
    FROM Telefone
    INNER JOIN Paciente
    ON Telefone.ID_Paciente=Paciente.ID_Paciente where Paciente.Nome=?";
PreparedStatement st = c.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1,nome);
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
while(res.next())
{
//your code to retrieve
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that (not tested):

```
final String sql = "SELECT t.DDD, t.Telefone FROM Telefone t" + 
                   " LEFT JOIN Paciente p ON (t.ID_Paciente = p.ID_Paciente)" + 
                   " WHERE p.Nome = ?";
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stm = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con = c.getConnection();
    stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    stm.setString(1, nome);

    rs = stm.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("DDD = %d, Telefone = %s", 
            rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2)));
    }
} catch (final SQLException e) {
    // TODO handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
        if (stm != null) {
            stm.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```